# Consulta de un tabledlayout

Tags: android, android-studio

amigos del foros, esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, se posee un tabla en un fragment el cual se presenta a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se aprecia en la imagen, el problema es que no realiza los separadores en todas las columnas, les presento el código xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colID"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/id"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colFilas"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/item"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colRepuestos"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/repuestos"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colUnidad"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/unidad2"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colCantidad"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/cantidad1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
</TableRow>
```

y este es el código de la clase en la cual se controla la tabla:

```
public class TableDynamic {
private TableLayout tableLayout;
private Context context;
private String[] header;
private ArrayList<String[]> data;
private TableRow tableRow;
private TextView txtCell;
private int indexC;
private int indexR;
private boolean multiColor = false;
int firtColor, secondColor, textColor, colorLinea;

public TableDynamic(TableLayout tableLayout, Context context) {
    this.tableLayout = tableLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

public void addHeader(String[] header) {
    this.header = header;
    createHeader();
}

public void addData(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
    this.data = data;
    createDataTable();
}

private void newRow() {
    tableRow = new TableRow(context);
}

private void newCell() {
    txtCell = new TextView(context);
    txtCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txtCell.setTextSize(18);
}

private void createHeader() {
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        newCell();
        txtCell.setText(header[indexC++]);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell, newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}

private void createDataTable() {
    String info;
    for(indexR=1;indexR<= data.size();indexR++) {
        newRow();
        for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++) {
            newCell();
            String[] row = data.get(indexR-1);
            info = (indexC<row.length)?row[indexC]:"";
            txtCell.setText(info);
            tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}

private TableRow.LayoutParams newTableRowParams() {
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(1,1,1, 1);
    params.weight = 1;
    return params;
}

public void addItems(String[] item) {
    String info;
    data.add(item);
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        newCell();
        info = (indexC < item.length) ? item[indexC++] : "";
        txtCell.setText(info);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell, newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, data.size());
    reColoring();
    reColoringLinea();
}

public void backgroundHeader(int color) {
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        txtCell = getCell(0, indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}

public void backgroundData(int firtColor, int secondColor) {
    for (indexR = 1; indexR <= data.size(); indexR++) {
        multiColor = !multiColor;
        for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
            txtCell = getCell(indexR, indexC);
            txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multiColor) ? firtColor : secondColor);
        }
    }
    this.firtColor = firtColor;
    this.secondColor = secondColor;
}

public void lineColor(int color) {
    indexR = 0;
    while (indexR <= data.size()) {
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    this.colorLinea = color;
}

public void textColorData(int color) {
    for (indexR = 1; indexR <= data.size(); indexR++) {
        for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
            getCell(indexR, indexC).setTextColor(color);
        }
    }
    this.textColor = color;
}

public void textColorHeader(int color) {
    indexC = 0;
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        getCell(0, indexC++).setTextColor(color);
    }
}

public void reColoring() {
    indexC = 0;
    multiColor=!multiColor;
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        txtCell = getCell(data.size() - 1, indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multiColor) ? firtColor : secondColor);
        txtCell.setTextColor(textColor);
    }
}

public void reColoringLinea(){
    indexR = 0;
    while (indexR <= data.size()) {
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(colorLinea);
    }
}

private TableRow getRow(int index) {
    return (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(index);
}

private TextView getCell(int rowIndex, int columIndex) {
    tableRow = getRow(rowIndex);
    return (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(columIndex);
}
}
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar, he tratado todo el día de solucionarlo y no he podido, ya que anteriormente había hecho tabledlayout con solo tres columnas y ahora son cinco, soy nuevo en estas lides de android studio y de a poco estoy aprendiendo cada día más, desde ya muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias.

Comment: Te refieres al separador entre ingreso y repuestos?

Comment: @Jorgesys muy buenas amigo, te cuento que ya solucione el problema el día Miércoles, revisando línea a línea tanto los xml como la clase, pero el problema estaba en el fragment de java, no estaban en los inflater y en la declaración los campos, por un error infantil, así que mis disculpas de antemano a la comunidad por el tiempo para todos, pero de todas maneras muchas gracias